# dynamic rolling period for std. deviation without using a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is it possible without using a loop to make the following code `std_dev_data = np.array(df["Data"].rolling().std())` to have a dynamic rolling window whereby the window is the position in the index / df. E.g 9th item has a rolling period of 9 the 1000 item has a rolling period of 1000?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom indexer window:

```
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer

class CustomIndexer(BaseIndexer):

    def get_window_bounds(self, num_values, min_periods, center, closed):
    
        start = np.zeros(num_values, dtype='int64')
        end = np.arange(1, num_values+1, dtype='int64')
        return start, end  

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'data':np.arange(10)})
df["data"].rolling(CustomIndexer()).mean()
```

The output looks like:

```
0    0.0
1    0.5
2    1.0
3    1.5
4    2.0
5    2.5
6    3.0
7    3.5
8    4.0
9    4.5
```

This article explains the flexibility of the `get_window_bounds` function: [5 new features in pandas 1.0 you should know about](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-new-features-in-pandas-1-0-you-should-know-about-fc31c83e396b)